# Derivative with a fraction freaks me out

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation, fractions, machine-learning

I have this:

$L(\mu, \sigma^2) = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2$

and I need to end up here:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^2}L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2$

---

But when I try to work things out, I do:

$L(\mu, \sigma^2) = -2^{-1}(\sigma^2)^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2 = -2^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2(\sigma^2)^{-1}$

thus

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^2}L(\mu, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2\space\sigma^2$

What am I missing? :/

Comment: You wrote `\frac{\theta}{\theta\sigma^2}`. Do you actually mean `\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^2}`? Note, $\frac{d}{d x} x^{-1} = -x^{-2}$.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what you mean, English is not my mother tongue. What I have to do is to take the derivate of L() w/ respect to σ². So yes I think this is what you mean by partial derivate @Tobias! Oh that's it Tobi! Because it's a negative exponent, it doesn't work the same as with a positive one! Do you want me to delete the question or are you going to post an answer please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think $-2^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2$ is just a multiplier of $\sigma^{-2}$ and notice $\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^2} \sigma^{-2} = (-1)(\sigma^2)^{-2}$ .

So you get $\frac{\partial}{\partial\sigma^2}L(\mu, \sigma^2) = -2^{-1}(\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2) (-1)(\sigma^2)^{-2} = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2 $.

Comment: Do you actually mean that $-2^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\mu)^2$ is a multiplier of $\sigma^{-2}$? Mind the sign!